# const object& return value from a method, best practice

Tags: c++

My C++ knowledge are minimal, for this i'm asking this:

I have a pointer to an object of type `Ndb` and i do this:

```
Ndb* myObj=new Ndb();
NdbError err=myObj->getNdbError();
//Do some work;
//Finish the job
delete(myObj);
```

The method's signature for `getNdbError` is:

`const NdbError& getNdbError() const`

According to the signature, who must take care of free the memory for the `NdbError`? the `const` before `NdbError&` means that i can only read the result and i should not to anything else?
I don't wont to leave some memory area allocated but not referenced.

EDIT:
According to the ansers its better to show more of this use case. I have a wrapper beetween a C++ object and C methods:

```
void* WINAPI new_Ndb(void* cluster_connection,const char* catalogname,const char* schemaName)
{

    Ndb_cluster_connection* co=(Ndb_cluster_connection*)cluster_connection;
    Ndb* tmpN=new Ndb(co,catalogname,schemaName);
    return (void*)tmpN;
}

void WINAPI Ndb_dispose(void* obj)
{
    delete (Ndb*)obj;
    obj=0;
}

const ndberror_struct WINAPI Ndb_getNdbError(void* obj)
{
    Ndb* tmp=(Ndb*)obj;

    NdbError res=tmp->getNdbError();    
    ndberror_struct tmpRes;
    tmpRes=(ndberror_struct)res;
    return tmpRes;
}
```

NdbError define an operator overloading:

```
  operator ndberror_struct() const {
    ndberror_struct ndberror;
    ndberror.status = (ndberror_status_enum) status;
    ndberror.classification = (ndberror_classification_enum) classification;
    ndberror.code = code;
    ndberror.mysql_code = mysql_code;
    ndberror.message = message;
    ndberror.details = details;
    return ndberror;
  }
```

What will appen when i make a call to

`const ndberror_struct WINAPI Ndb_getNdbError(void* obj)?`

The Ndberror will go out of scope but i keep the data because are copied?
`message` and `details` are `char*` so they will be freed when the return value ndb_error_struct will go out of scope?

Answer (score 2):

It most probably returns a reference to a data member, you don't need to `delete` it.

`err` will be a copy of the returned value from `getNdbError`, but as it's a stack variable, it will be destroyed at the end of the scope - nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a reference to an object that's managed by `myObj`; perhaps one of its members. You don't need to do anything to release that object; `myObj` should take care of it when it is destroyed.

You are using the returned reference to initialise an automatic variable `err` to be a copy of it. Like all automatic variables, it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope. You don't need to do anything to release that object either.

However, you should probably make `myObj` an automatic variable too, unless you have a good reason for dynamic allocation. Your code will have a memory leak if anything throws an exception between `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

The `getNdbError()` returns a const reference to a `NdbError` object.  You do not `delete` references.  You only `delete` something you `new`ed.

You assign the return of `getNdbError` to an `NdbError` object with automatic lifetime, as opposed to *dynamic* lifetime:

```
NdbError err=myObj->getNdbError();
```

`err` here is an automatic variable.  It will be destroyed automatically when it "falls out of scope."

It's interesting to note that, if the code you provided is the same as it is in your project, `err` will be destroyed *after* `myObj`, which you `delete` properly.  If there is a link between `err` and `myObj` which will cause undefined behavior or some other bad stuff in `err`'s destructor since `myObj` no longer exists, you may have to revisit your design.

I would strongly recommend either not using dynamic allocation at all, or if you must then at least wrap it in an RAII construct like a smart pointer so that allocation and deallocation can be handled in a more structured manner.

Comment: I added some more information about the use case, should be something related to you answer

Answer (score 1):

The function `const NdbError& getNdbError() const;` returns a constant reference to an `NdbError`.

Your `NdbError err` copy will automatically be deleted at the end of the function.

However rather than making a copy it should be a constant reference, i.e. change:

```
 NdbError err=myObj->getNdbError();
```

to

```
 const NdbError& err=myObj->getNdbError();
```

then it's clear that `myObj` takes care of the memory for the `NdbError`.